# C# : add Main methods in classes to quicktest

Tags: c#

I am more of a Java guy, and usually the convenient thing with Java is that you can just add a Main method on the fly in various classes to then execute them individually with a raw right-click -> run.

Right now, I have an ASP.NET application, and I am writing a package inside of it that I need to test individually. A little Main function, added on the fly to print things in the console, as described above, is what I would like to have. I tried simply adding one but of course Visual Studio doesn't notice it. At the moment I develop the package in anoher console application to bypass the trouble..

What would you suggest if you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way I do single class tests is by using a [unit test framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) like [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/).

This allows me to instantiate and test a class in isolation.

If the class has dependencies, I may also use a [mocking framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use) to mock those out.

Comment: One of the (many) reasons I love unit tests, it that they can be (mis)used as an on-the-fly scratch-pads for some quick and dirty concept code, as they can be run in isolation to the system, while having access to most of it.

Comment: @SWeko - Yep. I have had test classes that were nothing but execution harnesses for certain types of code.

Answer (score 1):

A good suite of Unit Tests would probably go a long way to doing what you need.